# Active class breaking on state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So here's the thing. I have this ng-class on my header item for projects:

```
ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('project')}"
```

My main view for projects is called `home`, the projects themselves are actually under an abstract project state.

Home:

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: '/views/project-list-view.html',
  controller: 'ProjectListCtrl'
})
```

Project:

```
.state('project', {
  template: '<ui-view/>',
  url: '/project',
  abstract: true,
  controller: function ($scope) {
    //
  }
})
.state('project.view', {
  url: '/:slug',
  params: {
    id: null,
    slug: null
  },
  templateUrl: '/views/project-view.html',
  controller: 'ProjectViewCtrl'
})
```

So the problem with this is that when I navigate from my home state (project list) to the project view page, the menu item loses it's active class. When I refresh the page after navigating, it works though. Why is this not working properly and how do I overcome this?

Edit: Had `ui-sref-active` in the title, but that is not the relevant part that's breaking.

Edit2: http://plnkr.co/edit/kwLBOFgBz0dYaKnavSum?p=preview

Comment: You can't get it to work like that. Because you move from the `home state` to the `project state`, so of course, `home` is not active anymore and neither `includes project state`. To get what you want, you'll have to define `.state('project')` as your `root/home`. So instead of `.state('home')` change it to `.state('project')`

Comment: How can I have the root page (being the project list) to have "/" as the url and the other project (sub-) pages to have the /project prefix? Having multiple slashes in routes break the app when refreshing, so I can't just have "/project/id/" as a route.

Comment: And the issue is actually that my current solution almost works, I mean, after refreshing the page after the route change it works, so it means there must be something I can trigger somewhere to fix this, right?

Comment: Why do you even have "ui-sref-active=active" tag in ur <li>'s when you have ng-class in it. Please remove this ui-sref-active="active" from the <li>. Something like below :
<li ui-sref="home" ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('project')}">Link to somewhere</li>

Comment: Because of the "home" state, that is linked through the route. I want other states ('project' and its sub-states) to also make it active, that's why I have the ng-class there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it your way, what you can do is create a `Run Block` for your app and everytime you change the route, look to see if it includes `the project state`:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {

    $rootScope.projectState = $state.includes('project') || $state.includes('home');

  });

}]);
```

Then, in your `index file`:

```
<!-- remove ui-sref-active -->
<li ui-sref="home" ng-class="projectState ? 'active' : '' ">Link to somewhere</li>
```

And here is your modified [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/idk2WFEfDkkKe78UUzCf?p=preview)

Comment: Try going to a single project and then clicking the top menu item to go back to the list - it's not active .______. It behaves about just as it did before on my local as well.

Comment: It works when I go back to the home view now, but still no active class when I navigate to a project. I put console.log($rootScope.projectState); in the run block's $stateChangeSuccess, which returned true every time, yet no active class :-(

Comment: have you removed `ui-sref-active` from the `home` link?

Comment: Now I did, and it seems to be fine. Hooray! <3

Answer (score 0):

In your check you use `$state.includes` ([API reference with example](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateincludesstatename--params)) which check if the state includes previous one. Which is true `project.view` includes `project` as a parent state.

You should use `$state.is()` instead of such check.

Comment: That is not working at all, not even after I refresh the page.

Comment: maybe you can reproduce the problem in plunkr.co ?

Comment: I edited the original post. When you navigate to the project, the item is not active. You can't really refresh the page there though.